# Specify beginning and end limits for 24 hour time axis in ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm plotting wind speed vs. time for data collected overnight, from 16:00 to 06:00. I want the graph to show these hours consecutively, from 16:00 to 06:00, with midnight closer to the center of the x-axis. My current graph puts noon in the center.

Here is my current graph:

[image: Wind speed vs time with noon as the midpoint]

Reprex code:

```
wind_speed <- structure(list(time_start = structure(c(0, 3600, 7200, 10800, 
                                        14400, 18000, 21600, 57600, 61200, 64800, 68400, 72000, 75600, 
                                        79200, 82800), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
               wind_avg = c(1.60133333333333, 1.54866666666667, 0.900666666666667, 
                            1.28766666666667, 1.78533333333333, 0.678666666666667, 1.00733333333333, 
                            0.531, 0.821666666666667, 0.119666666666667, 0.401333333333333, 
                            0.501333333333333, 0.769333333333333, 1.797, 1.52266666666667
               ), time_of_day = c("00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", 
                                  "05:00", "06:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", 
                                  "21:00", "22:00", "23:00")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = wind_speed, aes(x = time_start, y = wind_avg))+
  geom_point()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
library(tidyverse)

#create character vector of measurement start times
wind_speed <- wind_speed %>% mutate(time_of_day = strftime(time_start, format = "%H:%M"))

ggplot(data = wind_speed, aes(x = time_of_day, y = wind_avg))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00","00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to transform your x variable into time class. Better: datetime. Why date? Adding the "date" information will help R knowing that the hours 0 to 6 are supposed to come after midnight. You kind of make your own life really difficult if you omit this information.

If you don't have that date information, I'd add a random date, for example, today.

You can then use `scale_x_datetime` which will automatically give you the right limits. (Actually, you don't even need to add it, as ggplot will automatically recognise the date time class.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

wind_speed %>% 
  # add "day", then convert to actual date time class
  # using Sys.Date is random, just to get a date. 
  mutate(day = as_date(ifelse(time_of_day <="06:00", Sys.Date()+1, Sys.Date())),
    time_of_day = ymd_hm(paste(day, time_of_day))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = time_of_day, y = wind_avg))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>